# Replace the last bit of jQuery with d3.js - a selection with css-attribute change

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

Here is the last bit of jQuery in the code - like this everything works:

```
var colourchange = function () {
  var my_selection = d3.select(this);
  var selection_class = my_selection.attr("class");

  $("." + selection_class)
    .css("fill", "yellow");
};
```

To avoid the jQuery library (just for this line!) I am trying to replace it by `d3.js` code - which is the mainpart of the code anyway. Here is what I've got:

```
var colourchange = function () {
  var my_selection = d3.select(this);
  var selection_class = my_selection.attr("class");

  d3.selectAll("." + selection_class)
    .attr("fill", "yellow");
};
```

But it just doesn't work. I am pretty sure I am missing something very obvious.

edit: Maybe I should mention how I am calling this function...

```
<d3 - selection>
    .data(my_data)
    .enter().append("rect")
    .attr(...) etc.
    .on("mouseover", colourchange)
```

The effect of the function should be applied to the element on which the mouse hovers AND to some other elements with the same class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change `.attr("fill", "yellow")` to `.style("fill", "yellow")`

Using .attr() results in `<rect fill="yellow" ...>` instead of `<rect style="fill: yellow;" ...>` which might be causing your problem.

Comment: Bingo! Thank you very much - best part is: After submitting the question, I was somewhat unhappy about my chosen title "css-attribute" instead of "css-style" - but still I didn't realise that I should change .attr to .style ! lol